# Can I safely abort a Windows 8 update-restart?

Tags: windows-8.1, power, windows-update, updates

My Windows 8.1 laptop is stuck in a bout of 50 updates. These are horrendously slow and are delaying my work. Can I safely interrupt the update process, i.e. issue an ACPI power off?

Comment: It should be fine, and if it's not you can always use a system restore point.

Comment: This entirely depends on the update.  Its best to just leave it alone.  I have done it before.  But it is risky we cannot predict what will happen.

Comment: That *should* be an option/feature, automatic updates or not, it's no fun being held hostage waiting an unknown time at shutdown